# Django Manager-Employee relation

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I need some support for this problem i'm facing right now. I created a django app that allows a user(Manager) to register, the user(Manager) can then log in and create accounts for the Employees, they receive an email to set a password, and then can log in, having limited accesibility to the platform.

So far I managed to have the manager be able to, edit, activate-deactivate the employee account and even delete it, but there is no relation between the users. If I log in with 2 manager accounts, they both can see all the employee accounts in my employee_list.
how can I create a OneToOne relation between the manager and employee so that the manager who created his employee accounts can see them.

```
class Manager(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_manager = models.BooleanField(default=True)

class Employee(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    manager = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='employees', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_employee = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
            return self.user.username
```

so far this is what I came up with
Any help will be so much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer would be to keep a field on the Employee-model that is a One-to-One relation to a User-object. When an employee is created, set this field to the current logged in user performing the action. Only thing you should think about is, what happens if the manager is deleted. The employee still exists, so maybe set it to null or set it to an mock-user object (in my app I have a function that gets or creates an user with name as deleted)